# MongoDB Connection in Server

Tags: php, mongodb, drupal-7

When I try to connect MongoDB from my Drupal site, I am getting this error "

> MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException: Authentication
>   failed. in MongoDB\Driver\Server->executeCommand()

Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [Failed to resolve '2018@199.188.207.96'] in MongoDB\Driver\Manager->selectServer() (line 548 of /home/epixel/public_html/newproject/financial-academy/sites/all/modules/custom/afl_mongodb/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php).